# The meaning of "that long"

Tags: meaning, tenses

Please, what is the meaning of that long in this sentence:

> No, I will not have been living here that long.

Comment: This is a very unlikely construction. There would have to have been [!] some preliminary question or statement such as, *In five years, will you have been living here for a long time?*, which is barely plausible. But in general, the *... that long* term means for not a long time, if it is preceded (as in your example) by a negative.

Comment: The only weirdness in the sentence is the use of the word "will." Otherwise, "no I haven't lived/been living here that long" is perfectly common.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult without the full context but here is a guess ....

> Q. When you move house next week, will you be sentimental about this house?
>   A. No, I will not have been living here **that long**.

is same as

> No, I will not have been living here **very long**.

or perhaps even

> No, I will not have been living here **long enough to care about it**.

or

> No, I will not have been living here **particularily long**.

Here is an example on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUgOtitc7aU) courtesy of Snoop Dogg.

Comment: I believe that "long enough to care about it"  is by far the best of these three options. I understand "that long" to mean "as long as that"; i.e., a comparison to an amount (of time) that would have been mentioned earlier in the conversation. For example, "Did you see the subway get built?" implicitly identifies the time since the subway was built, and "will you be sentimental about this house?" implicitly means "have you been living here long enough to care about it?"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer that without more context, it's difficult to say. But I'm going to go the other route and say that it could be referring to a specific length of time:

> "On September 1st, anyone who's lived in this building for one year
>   will get a rent deduction. Do you qualify?"
>
> "No, I will not have been living here that long."

Here, "that long" means one year, the time specified within the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> No, I will not have been living here that long.

No / I / will have been living / not / here / that / long

Interjection / subject, pronoun / linking verb phrase / adverb negating the verb phrase to mean the opposite of the phrase / noun, predicate nominative / "that" as an adverb / adjective

The person is saying that in the future he or she doesn't expect to be living where he or she is at for very long. For example, you might say to the person, "Hey, a new grocery store in the neighborhood is planned to start construction in about two years. Isn't that great?"

"No, I will not have been living here that long. I plan to move when my lease is up at the end of this year."

Back to the diagram...

"here" is noun being modified by the adjective "long" which is being modified by "that" in its adverb form per definition:

"No, I will not have been living *at this place* (here) *to the degree or extent indicated by a gesture* (that) *lasting or continuing for a great amount of time* (long).

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/here

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long